# Saltstack grouping commands

Tags: python, salt-stack

If I have to execute the following 3 commands, how do I group them so I only have to call one?

```
salt '*' git.fetch cwd=/var/git/myproject opts='--all' user=git
salt '*' git.pull cwd=/var/git/myproject opts='origin master'
salt '*' nginx.signal reload
```

I can use fabric to put those in a single function say `deploy` which might accept a minion name then run through master, but I'm wondering if saltstack has something built-in?

Comment: Have you thought about creating a state where you simply run commands but have to wait for another state to finish and so on?

Comment: why the down vote? This is an old question, now a days I'd create a custom state file and pass as param to `state.sls` module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a good candidate for a custom module.

You can read about creating custom modules here: http://docs.saltstack.com/ref/modules/index.html.
Place your custom module in /srv/salt/_modules  (the default location) and then run

```
salt \* saltutil.sync_modules
```

Your module will then be available to run on your minions.

If your module is named 'deploy' and the function is 'mysite', then your custom command will look like this:

```
salt \* deploy.mysite
```

If you want to target a specific minion then it will look like this:

```
salt 'minion_name' deploy.mysite
```

Comment: You can actually execute these all in one run as well:
    salt '*' git.fetch,git.pull,nginx.signal "cwd=/var/git/myproject opts='--all' users=git","cwd=/var/git/myproject opts='origin master'","reload"